# NotifyIcon Text not shown on mouseover since Windows 10

Tags: c#, text, windows-10, notifyicon

I wrote a little app calculating the time I'm active working at the PC. The time was displayed at a `System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon.Text`. It worked fine on *Win7*. With a `mouseover` it showed the actual worktime. But now I have upgraded to *Win10* and the Program is still working (checked by debugging it) but the `.Text` is not shown anymore. It doesn't pop up.

Someone with the same problems? Or a solution?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: Same issue here, totally broken in Win10